# Have a for loop inside php code

Tags: php, ajax, loops, for-loop

I have a php script that gets responses for a form. Thing is, there are 20 different forms. For form 1, the POST gets the following values and stores them into variables.

```
$numberNa1=$_POST['numberNa1'];
$numbern1=$_POST['numbern1'];
$numberoi1=$_POST['numberoi1'];
$numbers1=$_POST['numbers1'];
$numberf1=$_POST['numberf1'];
```

I have this code that gets the id numbers from a form (ajax). I wish to repeat the same code 19 other times, so basically loop that line of code, but replace the number in the variable with another number. So for example, I wish the next chunk of code to be `$numberNa2=$_POST['numberNa2'];` and so on. This file is to be pure PHP.

Comment: [`extract()`](http://php.net/extract).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap them in `{}:`
sing `${}` is a way to create dynamic variables, simple example:

```
for($i=0;$i<19;$i++) {

${"numberNa" . $i} = $_POST['numberNa'.$i];
${"numbern" . $i} = $_POST['numbern'.$i];
${"numberoi" . $i} = $_POST['numberoi'.$i];
${"numbers" . $i} = $_POST['numbers'.$i];  
${"numberf" . $i} = $_POST['numberf'.$i];  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this:

```
$i = 1;
while(isset($_POST['numberNa'.$i]))
{
    $numberNa = $_POST['numberNa'.$i];
    $numbern = $_POST['numbern'.$i];
    $numberoi = $_POST['numberoi'.$i];
    $numbers = $_POST['numbers'.$i];
    $numberf = $_POST['numberf'.$i]; 

    // ... your code

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: With this, how can I write every variable into a text file? I use `fwrite($myfile, $numbern1. "\r\n");/*Number*/` instead this 19 other times?

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=1;$i<19;$i++){
    $numberNa.$i = $_POST['numberNa'.$i];
    $numbern.$i = $_POST['numbern'.$i];
    $numberoi.$i = $_POST['numberoi'.$i];
    $numbers.$i = $_POST['numbers'.$i];
    $numberf.$i = $_POST['numberf'.$i]; 

}
```

Comment: With this, how can I write every variable into a text file? I use `fwrite($myfile, $numbern1. "\r\n");/*Number*/` instead this 19 other times?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for($i=1 ;isset($_POST['numberNa'.$i]);$i++)
{
    $numberNa = $_POST['numberNa'.$i];
    $numbern = $_POST['numbern'.$i];
    $numberoi = $_POST['numberoi'.$i];
    $numbers = $_POST['numbers'.$i];
    $numberf = $_POST['numberf'.$i]; 
}
```

Comment: With this, how can I write every variable into a text file? I use `fwrite($myfile, $numbern1. "\r\n");/*Number*/` instead this 19 other times?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 
for($i=1; $i<=20; $i++)
{

    if(isset($_POST['numberNa'.$i]))
    {
        $numberNa.$i = $_POST['numberNa'.$i];
        fwrite($myfile, $numberNa.$i."\r\n");
    }
    if(isset($_POST['numbern'.$i]))
    {
        $numbern.$i = $_POST['numbern'.$i];
        fwrite($myfile, $numbern.$i."\r\n");
    }
    if(isset($_POST['numberoi'.$i]))
    {
        $numberoi.$i = $_POST['numberoi'.$i];
        fwrite($myfile, $numberoi.$i."\r\n");
    }
    if(isset($_POST['numbers'.$i]))
    {
        $numbers.$i = $_POST['numbers'.$i];
        fwrite($myfile, $numbers.$i."\r\n");
    }
    if(isset($_POST['numberf'.$i]))
    {
        $numberf.$i = $_POST['numberf'.$i];
        fwrite($myfile, $numberf.$i."\r\n");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: With this, how can I write every variable into a text file? I use `fwrite($myfile, $numbern1. "\r\n");/*Number*/` instead this 19 other times?

Comment: i've edited the code please check... and also use `$myfile = fopen('myfile.txt',"w");`